# splitting string a multiple delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to split a string in a pandas dataframe column like

```
coordinates(gDNA)
chr10:g.89711916T>A
```

into tab separated fields

```
chr\start\ref\alt

chr10\t89711916\tT\tA
```

in pandas.

So far I've tried

```
df[['chr','others']] = df['coordinates(gDNA)'].str.split(':',expand=True)
```

and extracted the first part, but not sure what to do for the rest

Comment: Is possible use separator `:g.` ? Is possible add more data to sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df[['chr','start', 'alt']] = df['coordinates(gDNA)'].str.split(':g.|>',expand=True)
df[['start','ref']] = df['start'].str.extract('(\d+)(\D+)')
print (df)
     coordinates(gDNA)    chr     start alt ref
0  chr10:g.89711916T>A  chr10  89711916   A   T
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df[['chr','start','ref','alt']] = df['coordinates(gDNA)'].str.extract('(\w+).*?(\d+)(\w+).*?(\w+)')
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more regex?

Comment: @jezrael Here is a full [explanation](https://regex101.com/r/44iKlO/1). Yet, I'm not sure this expression is universal. We need to see more data

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['coordinates(gDNA)'],
    data=[['chr10:g.89711916T>A']]
)

def parser(x):
    ch, x = x.split(':g.')
    start = int(x[:-3])
    ref = x[-3]
    alt = x[-1]
    return dict(chr=ch, start=start, ref=ref, alt=alt)

pd.DataFrame([*map(parser, df['coordinates(gDNA)'])], df.index)


  alt    chr ref     start
0   A  chr10   T  89711916
```